# Change Data Type in body of Email VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to change the data type of a range in the body of an email generated with VBA?
Here is my current code:

```
Sub Email()
Dim r As Worksheet
Dim appOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim mEmail As Outlook.MailItem

Set r = Worksheets("Releases")
Set appOutlook = New Outlook.Application
Set mEmail = appOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With mEmail
    .To = "" 
    .CC = "" 
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Test"
    .HTMLBody = "Test " & r.Range("A1")
    .Display
End With
Set mEmail = Nothing
Set appOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

is it possible to return r.Range("A1") as a data type currency?
in the worksheet the data type is currency, but when the email is created the data type is not carried over. I have tried `r.Range("A1").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"` but the email body just returns 'False'

Comment: `& Format$(r.Range("A1").Value, "$#,##0.00")`.

Comment: That did it. Thanks I appreciate the quick response